# How can I subtract two inputted dates (Years, Months, Days) taking Leap Years into consideration

Tags: c++, date, time

I have been trying to figure out how to accurately subtract one date from another in C++. Both will be received through user input. I thought that by creating a class, along with the use of `<ctime>`, I would be able to do this but I have yet to find how to do so while taking Leap years into consideration, which would be the cause for the loss of accuracy that it might have.

Here is how I was approaching the task:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class Year {
private:
    struct tm date3;
    struct tm date2;
    struct tm date;
    int FirstYear, SecondYear;
    int FirstMonth, SecondMonth;
    int FirstDay, SecondDay;

public:
    int DateCalculus(struct tm* date, struct tm* date2);
    void ResultShown();
};

int Year::DateCalculus(struct tm* date, struct tm* date2) {
    struct tm date3;
    date3.tm_year = date->tm_year - date2->tm_year;

    date3.tm_mon = date->tm_mon - date2->tm_mon;
    date3.tm_mday = date->tm_mday - date2->tm_mday;
}

void Year::ResultShown() {
    cout<< date3;
}

int main() {

    struct tm Date = { 0, 0, 12 };  
    struct tm Date2 = { 0, 0, 12 };
    int Firstyear, SecondYear;
    int Firstmonth, SecondMonth;  
    int Firstday, SecondDay;

    cin >> Firstday; cout << "Day 1 " << endl;
    cin >> Firstmonth; cout << "Month 1 " << endl;
    cin >> Firstyear; cout << "Year 1 " << endl;
    cin >> SecondDay; cout << "Day 2 " << endl;
    cin >> SecondMonth; cout << "Month 2 " << endl;
    cin >> SecondYear; cout << "Year 2 " << endl;
    Date.tm_year = Firstyear;
    Date.tm_mon = Firstmonth;  
    Date.tm_mday = Firstday;   

    Year::DateCalculus(&Date, &Date2);

    cout << asctime(&Date2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider a much simpler task: computing the number of days since, for example, January 1, 1970, and your date in question. That's a relatively simple task, laughably trivial to implement. Once you have that done, computing the number of days between two dates involves nothing more than computing the number of days since 1/1/1970 and each one of the two dates, and then subtracting one result from the other one. Mission accomplished.

Comment: You could start by using `mktime()` to convert your `tm`s to seconds since the start of 1970.

Comment: You should look at [tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/?kw=tm) for the meaning of each field of the struct (unless you're already subtracting values when you input e.g. Year. Also, it looks like the `cout` prompts for each field are after the actual inputs?

Comment: A few other notes: in C++, you don't need `struct tm`; just `tm` is fine for declaring a variable of that type (ditto for `struct`/`class`/`enum`). Second, `ResultShown` attempts to use `date3`, which I don't see declared in any scope that it can see. Does this code compile? Finally, what is the actual question? See [ask] and [tour] (and [mcve]).

Comment: Here is a cookbook with algorithms for creating your own date class.  Each algorithm is thoroughly explained and tested.  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html